# Three.js orthographicCamera 'attachObject' does not exist on type 'OrthographicCameraProps' / Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

Iam trying to implement this to my project
https://codesandbox.io/s/4m0d0?file=/src/App.js:2017-2018

I get the error which I mentioned on title at this line

```
 <directionalLight ref={keyLight} castShadow intensity={6}>
    <orthographicCamera attachObject={['shadow', 'camera']} args={[-10, 10, 10, -10, 0.5, 30]} />
  </directionalLight>
```

Thanks for any help ..